# Script for multiple coupon code generation for CE 1.5x

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes, automation

Can anyone help me with the script and explanation to generate multiple coupon codes programatically since this feature is not present in Magento CE ver 1.5x. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename;

Varien_Profiler::enable();

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
function generateUniqueId($length = null){
$rndId = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1)); 
$rndId = strip_tags(stripslashes($rndId)); 
$rndId = str_replace(array(".", "$"),"",$rndId); 
$rndId = strrev(str_replace("/","",$rndId));
if (!is_null($rndId)){
return strtoupper(substr($rndId, 0, $length));
} 
return strtoupper($rndId);
} 
function getAllCustomerGroups(){
//get all customer groups
$customerGroups = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection();
$groups = array();
foreach ($customerGroups as $group){
$groups[] = $group->getId();
}
return $groups;
}
function getAllWbsites(){
//get all wabsites
$websites = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection();
$websiteIds = array();
foreach ($websites as $website){
$websiteIds[] = $website->getId();
}
return $websiteIds;
}

//read comments for each line
function generateRule(){
$uniqueId = 'Prefix10'.generateUniqueId(5);
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
$rule->setName('Test rule');
$rule->setDescription('10% off site wide');
$rule->setFromDate(date('2014-10-01'));// From : 1 Oct 2014
$rule->setToDate('2015-08-31');// To : 31 Aug 2015
$rule->setCouponCode($uniqueId);
$rule->setUsesPerCoupon();//number of allowed uses for this coupon
$rule->setUsesPerCustomer(1);//number of allowed uses for this coupon for each customer
$myarray = array("0", "1");
$rule->setCustomerGroupIds($myarray);//if you want only certain groups replace getAllCustomerGroups() with an array of desired ids 
$rule->setIsActive(1);
$rule->setStopRulesProcessing(1);//set to 1 if you want all other rules after this to not be processed
$rule->setIsRss(1);//set to 1 if you want this rule to be public in rss
$rule->setIsAdvanced(1);//have no idea what it means :)
$rule->setProductIds('');
$rule->setSortOrder(0);// order in which the rules will be applied


$rule->setSimpleAction('by_percent');
//all available discount types
//by_percent - Percent of product price discount
//by_fixed - Fixed amount discount
//cart_fixed - Fixed amount discount for whole cart
//buy_x_get_y - Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y)

$rule->setDiscountAmount('10');//the discount amount/percent. if SimpleAction is by_percent this value must be <= 100
$rule->setDiscountQty(1);//Maximum Qty Discount is Applied to
$rule->setDiscountStep(0);//used for buy_x_get_y; This is X
$rule->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);//set to 1 for Free shipping
$rule->setApplyToShipping(0);//set to 0 if you don't want the rule to be applied to shipping
$rule->setWebsiteIds(getAllWbsites());//if you want only certain websites replace getAllWbsites() with an array of desired ids

$conditions = array();
$conditions[1] = array(
'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
'aggregator' => 'all',
'value' => "1", //[UPDATE] added quotes on the value. Thanks Aziz Rattani [/UPDATE]
'new_child' => ''
);
//the conditions above are for 'if all of these conditions are true'
//for if any one of the conditions is true set 'aggregator' to 'any'
//for if all of the conditions are false set 'value' to 0.
//for if any one of the conditions is false set 'aggregator' to 'any' and 'value' to 0
/*$conditions['1--1'] = Array
(
'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_address',
'attribute' => 'base_subtotal',
'operator' => '>=',
'value' => 200
);*/
//the constraints above are for 'Subtotal is equal or grater than 200'
//for 'equal or less than' set 'operator' to '<='... You get the idea other operators for numbers: '==', '!=', '>', '<'
//for 'is one of' set operator to '()';
//for 'is not one of' set operator to '!()';
//in this example the constraint is on the subtotal
//for other attributes you can change the value for 'attribute' to: 'total_qty', 'weight', 'payment_method', 'shipping_method', 'postcode', 'region', 'region_id', 'country_id'

//to add an other constraint on product attributes (not cart attributes like above) uncomment and change the following:
/*
$conditions['1--2'] = array
(
'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found',//-> means 'if all of the following are true' - same rules as above for 'aggregator' and 'value'
//other values for type: 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_subselect' 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine'
'value' => 1,
'aggregator' => 'all',
'new_child' => '', 
);

$conditions['1--2--1'] = array
(
'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
'attribute' => 'sku',
'operator' => '==',
'value' => '12',
);
*/
//$conditions['1--2--1'] means sku equals 12. For other constraints change 'attribute', 'operator'(see list above), 'value'

$rule->setData('conditions',$conditions);
$rule->loadPost($rule->getData());
$rule->setCouponType(2);

/*$labels = array(1,3);
$labels[1] = "This is label for desktop site";//default store label
$labels[3] = "This is label for mobile site";*/ 

//add one line for each store view you have. The key is the store view ID


$rule->save();
//[UPDATE]if you work with Mangento EE and you want to link banners to your rule uncomment the line of code below
//Mage::getResourceModel('enterprise_banner/banner')->bindBannersToSalesRule($rule->getId(), array(1,2));//the array(1,2, ...) is the array with all the banners you want to link to the rule.
//[/UPDATE]
}

for ($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){//replace 200 with the number of coupons you want
generateRule();
}
```

?>